# Program executes correctly then segfaults

Tags: c++

At the end of the program, my array prints out properly, and then the program segfaults. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  struct item{
    char type[9];
    int price;
    bool wanted;
  };
  item items[20]; char temp[8]; 
  for (char i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    if (fscanf(file,
         "%[^,], %[^,], %d",
         items[i].type,
         temp,
         &items[i].price) != 3)
      break;
    else if (!strcmp(temp, "for sale"))
      items[i].wanted = false;
    else if (!strcmp(temp, "wanted"))
      items[i].wanted = true;
    else
      cout << "aaaagghghghghhhh!!!" << endl;
  }

  for (char i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    cout << items[i].type << endl;
    cout << items[i].price << endl;
    cout << items[i].wanted << endl;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array is declared with only 20 spaces, yet your loop goes to 100. Maybe change your array to have 100 spaces.

Use

```
 item items[100];
```

Overflowing arrays leads to undefined behavior. It is possible that your code wrote into memory required by the C++ run-time during program stack unwinding, etc.

Comment: OH MY GOSH I had that for debugging and forgot to change it! Agghghgh! This is my first C++ program coming from a Haskell/Python background where IT TELLS YOU IF YOU'RE OUT OF BOUNDS so sorry. Why does it cause a segfault tho? Shouldn't it just overwrite whatever is past the 20 mark?

Comment: @RenéG  Overflowing arrays leads to undefined behavior. See, my answer: I edited it.